# Port conflict in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, port, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create the following with a reverse proxy (the webs only work) but with the mail server, it gives port conflict error in docker-compose.

What I want is that the webs coexist with the mail service. For example mail.sitea.com

Any suggestion?

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  site-a:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '80'
    volumes:
      - /var/www/site-a/public_html/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=sitea.com

  site-b:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '80'
    volumes:
      - /var/www/site-b/public_html/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=siteb.com

  poste:
    image: analogic/poste.io
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    expose:
      - 25
      - 80
      - 443
      - 110
      - 143
      - 465
      - 587
      - 993
      - 995
    volumes:
      - /docker/mail:/data
    environment:
      - HTTPS=ON
      - DISABLE_CLAMAV=TRUE
```

OUTPUT

```
/docker# vim /docker/docker-compose.yml
root@adroconstruccion:/docker# docker-compose up -d
Removing docker_nginx-proxy_1
docker_site-b_1 is up-to-date
docker_site-a_1 is up-to-date
Starting 08fba2b58471_docker_nginx-proxy_1 ... error
Recreating docker_poste_1                  ...

ERROR: for 08fba2b58471_docker_nginx-proxy_1  Cannot start service nginx-proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 08fba2b58471_docker_nginx-proxy_1 (095659f459c1af8c729129074520b40800e528719727061bdbc4bfa25f6c37d5)Recreating docker_poste_1                  ... done

ERROR: for nginx-proxy  Cannot start service nginx-proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 08fba2b58471_docker_nginx-proxy_1 (095659f459c1af8c729129074520b40800e528719727061bdbc4bfa25f6c37d5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: It looks like there's already somebody listening on your localhost port 443, and the nginx container is trying to bind to that as well. If you have a web server running on your localhost either shut that down, or move the nginx container in your docker compose to bind to a port other than 443 on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `poste` with `network_mode: "host"` it will listen on those ports on the local network. So the port 443 listener in the poste service conflicts with `nginx-proxy`

Depending on what you're using the `poste` continer for you might be able to get away with just commenting out those ports (80 and 443) and just using the mail ports. Or you could remove the `network_mode: "host"` and maybe proxy them through nginx?